# Mutable Types in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I am writing a function that swaps the contents of two reference calls.

```
let swap (x : a ref) (y :'a ref) : unit =
```

where

```
type 'a ref = {mutable contents : 'a}
```

I do not know what approach to take in order to solve this. Do I use pattern matching?

This is my test case

```
let test () : bool = 
  let r1 = { contents = 5 } in
  let r2 = { contents = 6 } in
  let _ = swap r1 r2 in
  (6, 5) = (r1.contents, r2.contents)
;; 

run_test "Swap different" test
```

Comment: Instead of `{ contents = 5 }` you can just write `ref 5`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work?

```
let swap x y = 
  let z = !x in
  x := !y;
  y := z
```

Note that `:=` and `!` are just normal functions like so:

```
let (:=) r x = r.contents <- x
let (!) {contents} = contents
```

If you want to use own your type definition then you can do:

```
let swap' x y = 
  let z = x.contents in
  x.contents <- y.contents;
  y.contents <- z
```

Finally, if you're using batteries then you can just use `BatRef.swap` as defined here: http://ocaml-batteries-team.github.com/batteries-included/hdoc2/BatRef.html

Comment: I am still getting syntax errors. Is this because the output is not of type unit?

Comment: Where exactly are you getting these syntax errors? I've evaluated all of the code in my toplevel just fine.

Comment: I just edited my post to show you my test case. For some reason I keep on getting an error right next to the ;; of run_test saying "unexpected token ;;"

Comment: The code you've added works perfectly fine for me. I've edited the indentation a little for clarity and replaced `_` with `()`. Not sure if that was the error though. It does work though. Crap it says my edit needs to be peer reviewed. Not sure when you will be able to see it...